# Pivot a table in SQL without an aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with the following format:

```
ID    CODE    NAME    VALUE
p1    p       deflect Yes
a1    d       source  Prim
p1    p       source  Dim
```

I want to pivot to have the following:

```
ID    CODE    deflect    source
p1    p       Yes        DIM
a1    d       NULL       Prim
```

This is my current code:

```
SELECT *
from
(
    select [ID], [CODE], [NAME], [VALUE]
    FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE]
) SOURCE_TABLE
pivot
(
    max(VALUE)
    for [NAME] in ('deflect', 'source')
) PIVOT_TABLE;
```

But I'm getting:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'deflect'.
```

How would you write the pivot code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select [ID], [CODE], 
       max(case when [NAME] = 'deflect' then [VALUE] end) as deflect,
       max(case when [NAME] = 'source' then [VALUE] end) as source_
FROM [DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE]
group by [ID], [CODE]
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to just tell it to do a pivot for all values of the column instead of having to specify each?

Comment: You have to use the dynamic query in that case. that willnot be that much easy. You should apply such logics in application side rather than in the database